# How to insert (or change) one value to a multiple rows MVC 5 EF

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5

Good evening everyone,
Here is my question:
For example I have model like this:

```
[Table("Orders")]
public class Order
{
    [Key]
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public DateTime Generated { get; set; }
    public virtual ApplicationUser User { get; set; }
    public string UserId { get; set; }
    public string Content { get; set; }
}
```

And I want change UserId with signle user's Id in multiple checked orders at one time.
By default all UserId fields are empty.

```
public async Task<ActionResult> OrdersToChange(string[] orderIds)
    {

        //
        return View(orders);
    }
```

1. How can I get selected orders from database.
2. How can I assign chosen User to selected entries.
   Thanks a lot.

Comment: I got answer with this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41043586/update-mutiple-records-in-database-mvc-5-ef

Answer (score 1):

You can create a database context and then use Linq to compare id to get a specific user and also to read and write data into the database.

[Check out this link. It might be helpful.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj193542(v=vs.113).aspx)

Answer (score 1):

To update multiple rows with the same value without loading entities, you need a Batch Update library

See: [Entity Framework Batch Update Library](http://entityframework-plus.net/batch-update)

**Disclaimer**: I'm the owner of the project [Entity Framework Plus](http://entityframework-plus.net/)

Example

```
int currentUserId = 1;
var ctx = new MyContext();
ctx.Orders.Where(x => orderIds.Contains(x.Id))
          .Update(x => new Order { UserId = currentUserId });
```